# Simple Android app that sets the device's display to maximum brightness

Tags: android, display, accessibility

I am seeking recommendations for the very simplest of Android apps: An app that simply sets the brightness of the screen (display) to the device's maximum.

The only catch is that I want it to perform this action without any UI.  I'll be calling it via a gesture from a launcher, and so I can call it as an app, shortcut, or activity.  I don't want a tool that is always running a background service.

No ads. Price needs to be gratis. Must be compatible with Android 7.0.

I've searched quite a bit, and I'm surprised that I have yet found something so simple and useful.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to set maximum screen brightness using the Termux app with its Termux:API add-on app by issuing the `termux-brightness 255` command. You must grant the Termux app the android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS permission. It is possible to add that command as a widget on the home screen, but I do not know how to call it as an activity from a gesture.

Comment: Welcome James, and thank you! Do you know if that will all work if the device is not rooted.  IIRC, `adb` can be used to add the WRITE_SETTINGS permission without root, so I don't think that step will be an issue.

Comment: None of my android devices are rooted, and it worked quite well when I tested it the other day on my phone. It is running Android 9 and I had access to the WRITE_SETTINGS through the regular system settings menus.